# IIS websites inheriting settings from unknown origin

Tags: iis, configuration, web-config, iis-7.5

I am dealing with an IIS server that hosts 900+ websites. There are about a dozen that do not contain any web.config file, yet on their settings page > HTTP Redirect section the "redirect requests to this destination" is checked and a URL to one of the hosted websites is present inside the textbox below it. I cannot figure out where the checkbox's true value and the URL is coming from.

Note: If I turn off the checkbox a web.config file is created with the following line:

```
<httpRedirect enabled="false" />
```

While this kind of works it is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS Manager:

- Click on the website
- Open "Configuration Editor" under the "Server Components" section
- In the "Section" dropdown choose "system.webServer/httpRedirect" (or whichever section that has issues)
- In the "From" dropdown choose "ApplicationHost.config"
- Set or unset the properties
- Click "Apply"

You can now edit the website's web.config file manually or use the above interface.

[image: Screenshot - red section indicates the settings that are inherited]